# Core-data transformable attribute not allocated by default?

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a core data model with a Transformable attribute called `location`. However, when I create a new entity with `initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:`, `location` is `nil`.

Is that the expected behavior? I was expecting all the memory for a field in an entity to be allocated upfront. If this is the expected behavior, what is the recommended way to work around this? Is allocating memory for `location` in `awakeFromInsert` a good idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is expected. If you haven't given the entity any data how would it know what size to allocate. Even then, what would it do with that allocation because it isn't a real object and you can't really convert it into one. You should expect the property to hold `nil` if there is nothing there. You do no need to and should not want to fill it with some default empty allocation.

If you have a default object that you want to set then that's a different matter. Then `awakeFromInsert` could be a good option. The question is whether the default object should be saved into the store (and therefore be searchable). If not you might want to implement a custom accessor method to return your default object if the stored value is `nil`.